# ListView in UpdatePanel not Refreshing

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a ListView that's inside a UpdatePanel, UpdateMode = Conditional. It's a really large Listview, lots of templates, so I'm not showing details.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updListView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:ListView ID="lstvScanPreview" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lstvScanPreview_ItemDataBound">
       ...
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I also have a radiobutonlist outside of the update panel with a OnSelectedIndexChanged of

```
protected void rgbShowIssues_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (rgbShowIssues.SelectedIndex == 0)
       lstvScanPreview.DataSource = previewData.Data.Where(S => S.IssueType != ScanIssues.None);
   else
       lstvScanPreview.DataSource = previewData.Data;

   updListView.Update();
}
```

A breakpoint set inside this method does get hit, but the listview doesn't refresh. Other controls also have events with code-behind that call updListView.Update(), and these do work. If I trigger one of these other events after I clicking on the rgbShowIssues radiobuttonlist, then when the update does occur, I can see the changes I would have expected had the UpdatePanel refreshed when expected.

Any ideas why this isn't working?  Thanks.

Comment: your code seems fine. Is there anywhere you binding this listview beside `rgbShowIssues_SelectedIndexChanged`? ie. `PageLoad`, `PagePreRender`, ensure to check for `Page.IsPostBack`

Comment: Nice tip. The other controls that were working were calling a method that processed data and then bound the list. This event was just binding the list. I refactored the first method so that all paths are rebinding and then calling the Update() through the same method. Its better in that the list does now show all data, but for whatever reason the troublesome radiobuttonlist is somehow causing a full postback. I'm getting tired, I'll look at it fresh again tomorrow. Annoying but functional.